# Do you think class string implements interface comparable in Java

Tags: java, class, interface

I'm doing this for my own understanding and I don't understand this question.

> Assume there is an interface named comparable with the following
>   definition:

```
public interface Comparable { 
        int compareTo(Object obj);
     }
```

> Do you think class String implements interface Comparable? Provide a
>   reason for your answer.

I would say no because there is no string anywhere in the class, but I believe I am misunderstanding the question. Can Someone explain this one better for me?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html - But I guess the question is aimed at your explanation ... Do you use an older version of Java in that course?

Comment: I don't understand the question either. You have to _guess_ whether String implements this interface?

Comment: You're asked to consider the given `Comparable` interface and then give your educated opinion on whether that is something that `String` could or should implement.

Comment: The exact answer depends on a couple of things: whether this is `java.lang.Comparable` we're talking about or another interface with the same name, whether we're pre-Java 5 or not.

Answer (score 6):

You should look into the source code or the Java doc of the class `String`. It is explicitly implementing the interface `Comparable`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

> **java.lang**
>
> Class String
>
> java.lang.Object
>
> java.lang.String
>
> All Implemented Interfaces:
>
> Serializable, CharSequence, **Comparable< String >**

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to give you other point of view for the question and I'm goint to say **No, it doesn't.**

Since Java 6, java.lang.String can't implement that interface because that is not compatible with `Comparable<String>` and `Comparable` is not the same as `Comparable<String>`. The diference is that you **can't** compare an `String` with an `Object`

Comment: I've just read the documentation `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html` and It said that you need a parameterized parameter and yes, I just tried it

Comment: Just because generics make it slightly more complicated than that. `Comparable foo = "foo";` will compile for example. But if you then run `foo.compareTo(new Object())`, you'll get a `ClassCastException` at runtime. Whereas `"foo".compareTo(new Object())` will not even compile. It's all to do with the way type erasure works. The important thing though is that you can't compare a `String` to any object, it will fail either at compile time or runtime.

Comment: Your first example will compile but also you'll get a warn telling you that you are using raw data and the `ClassCastException` is  the result of using wrong the parameters. In fact, if you were done `Comparable<String> foo = "foo"` it wouldn't have compile either.

Comment: Yes, but the fact you can cast a `String` to `Comparable` strictly speaking would imply that `String` implements `Comparable`. (And in fact it really does, if you decompile the class file, you'll see a `public boolean compareTo(Object)` method in there.) But the compiler will try to do its best to prevent you from comparing strings with any non-string objects.

Answer (score 1):

String implements Comparable.

```
Why it does so?
```

So that sorting can be done on strings using compareTo method.
For example you want to sort employees based on their name and name is string so you use this as:-

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Employee implements Comparable {

    String name;

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Employee employeeAnother = (Employee) o;
        // natural alphabetical ordering by type
        // if equal returns 0, if greater returns +ve int,
        // if less returns -ve int
        return this.name.compareTo(employeeAnother.name);// String compareTo is
                                                            // called here
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(new Employee("Ramesh"));
        list.add(new Employee("Deepak"));
        list.add(new Employee("Vivek"));
        Collections.sort(list); // sorts using compareTo method
        for (Iterator iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Employee employee = (Employee) iter.next();
            System.out.println(employee);
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I have not used Generics to keep things simple. You will get few warnings but you can ignore these.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the given class implements some interfaces or other class you could use `instanceof`:

```
System.out.println("string" instanceof Comparable);
```

---

You could also try to execute method from the given interface:

```
"one".compareTo("two")
```

In this case your code will compile or appropriate error message will be shown.

---

However the best way is to read the source code of the given class. In this case you don't have to write any additional code. Also, a good IDE (like Eclipse, Intellij Idea) could help to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes!!
In Java 8; open Java doc and you will find below:

```
public final class String
    implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
```